# Torrent client allowing upload/download rate limit depending on the time of day

Tags: linux, bittorrent, bandwidth, vuze

With Azureus/Vuze, can we set an upload/download rate limit depending on the time of day ?

If not, do you know a torrent client allowing this ? Client must be available on Linux.

---

EDIT

After reading the answer, I learned that you can install plugins for Azureus/Vuze. There is one about scheduling. I've tried to install it but I got a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) (Mac OS X and Unix/Linux with GTK+ or Qt GUI) has a "speed limit" mode that can be scheduled.

Screenshot is from Mac OS X Version, but I believe they have that feature on all platforms.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I used it 2 years ago and I didn't notice about this feature.

Comment: @Luc You're welcome. Transmission development is quite active, it's possible that this feature is more recent than that.

Answer (score 5):

it's still in alpha stage, but µTorrent has a linux client that allows scheduling of rate limits [here](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux)

Comment: haven't used nano torrent on linux yet, but i liked a couple years ago on the windows side

Comment: @aking It's mu, used for micro, not nano ;)

Comment: @Daniel okies my bad

Answer (score 2):

[Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/) has scheduling through [a plugin](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins#DelugePluginsSupplied). It's available for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.